# Sending Invitations to Participate in Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am very new to Messenger platform and I'm trying to wrap my head around the types of things that are possible. In particular, I'm interested in using a bot as a "mediator" of communication among friends. For example, one could build build a bot to help make a group decision, like where four or five people will have lunch. Each person interacts only with the bot, the bot gathers lunch preferences, and communicates some type of optimal choice to all participants. This could require a back-and-forth discussion of preferences with each participant. Is that clear?

At this point, I'm wondering two things:

- How would a user initially invite another user into the conversation? Suppose user A starts talking to the bot and the bot tells user A, "Invite some friends to join us in this conversation". Can the bot actually send these invitations on behalf of user A? Or does invitation have to take place via some other out-of-band mechanism?
- Is messenger platform the most appropriate FB platform technology for creating this sort of interactive mediation app?

Thanks in advance, InterWebs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your idea correctly, it would be very difficult to build a bot that could chat with each person separately but offer a shared experience. When a user shares the bot with another user and the new user starts a chat, the bot has no way of knowing where the referral comes from, so there's really no way to know that the two users are linked.

What you could do is build a chat extension, which basically makes functionality from your bot available in a group chat:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions

Comment: Thanks @amuramoto. You sound like the right person to discuss this with. I am interested in mediation, specifically an app in which the users communicate with the central bot and do not talk directly with one another. (There are certainly other ways to do that!) I think the bot can know (a) which FB user sent it a message and (b) all of this user's FB friends who have also interacted with the bot. So the bot can, indeed, associate users, I think. Do you see my point?

Comment: a different example may clarify: Suppose one wants to build an app which will tell you aggregate statistics on your FB friends' favorite colors. You talk to the bot, tell it your favorite color, it gathers this information and periodically tells each user what fraction of their friends like blue best, red best, etc. Do you see any particular problem in constructing such an app using the Messenger platform? One problem I foresaw was the invitation issue. Maybe the bot can somehow prompt the user to share or like the bot's page with his/her friends and this would serve as an invite?

Comment: The main issue is the bot won't know which users are friends. Like I mentioned before, sharing the bot wouldn't allow you to make this association between users. The bot can potentially know that a user shared, but when the friends start interacting with the bot via the share, it would have no way of knowing the source.

One possibility (that is clunky) is you could provide a m.me link with a ref param of the first user's PSID, then associate that way when the ref is returned in the messaging_referrals event.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links

Comment: Thanks, amuramoto. I think I see the problem now. I had assumed the bot could get the list of friends through the Graph API, but I see the bot only sees PSID's, so it can't really execute /<user>/friends. Drat.

Comment: You could potentially get ASID by implementing FB Login in the Messenger Webview, but that's a lot of steps to adoption so the drop off rate would probably be undesirably high.